# Ifort gives segfault in OpenMP parallelized code when passing internal procedure as argument, but not gfortran

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, openmp, gfortran, intel-fortran

I have made a minimal example of my more complex Fortran code where I get segmentation fault when compiling and running with the Intel Fortran compiler ifort and not with the GNU compiler gfortran.

If I compile with `gfortran <source file> -fopenmp` it works.

If I compile with `ifort <source file> -qopenmp` I get segmentation fault after running it.

In the minimal example below it seems that the segmentation fault comes from y_index not having its initialized value at line 31 "g = x + y(y_index)". Why is that?

```f90
program segfault
    implicit none
    integer  :: i, y_index
    real(16) :: x(20), y(20)

    x = 1
    y = 1
    y_index = 5
    !$omp parallel do shared(x,y,y_index) num_threads(1)
    do i=1, size(x)
      print*, 'g(x) = ', f(g, x(i))
    end do
    !$omp end parallel do

contains
    
    real(16) function f(g, x)
        real(16), intent(in) :: x
        
        interface
          real(16) function g(x)
            real(16), intent(in) :: x
          end function
        end interface
        
        f = g(x)
    end function
    
    real(16) function g(x)
        real(16), intent(in) :: x
        g = x + y(y_index)
    end function
    
end program
```

I tried to play with the private, firstprivate and shared clauses of the OpenMP do construct. I also played with the kind parameter, and it seems to work with real(4) and real(8). But I need real(16). I also set the number of threads to 1 to check if the problems had to do with parallelization over multiple threads. The segmentation fault shows up anyway.

Comment: The code you are using is not trivial at all. It passes an internal function as argument and that is implemented using trampolines (https://stevelionel.com/drfortran/2009/09/02/doctor-fortran-in-think-thank-thunk/) and I am not sure what happens when you do this with OpenMP. It might be something that is not allowed in OpenMP or it might be a compiler bug. Try to move the function and `y_index` into a module.

Comment: I don't know if it's a compiler bug (probably) or some illegal code with OpenMP, but generally speaking accessing global variables from OpenMP regions is risky (although it should be OK as long as they are only read, not written).

Comment: As suggested by @VladimirFГероямслава, putting `g`, `y`, and `y_index` in separate module fixes the problem (I've tested)

Answer (score 0):

ifort 2021.10.0 uses OpenMP 5.0 version TR4 https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/fortran-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2023-2/openmp-support.html.

The OpenMP 5.0 version TR4 specification supports Fortran 2003, where internal procedure as dummy argument is not allowed. See  page 24 and 34 in https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-tr4.pdf.

Two possible solutions:

1. Put g into a module
2. Make a procedure pointer g_ptr => g and pass g_ptr into f.

Comment: The latest spec has removed this text. See page 35 of https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-2.pdf. I don't know what version Intel claims to support.

Comment: I changed the answer from referencing OpenMP 5.0 to OpenMP 5.0 TR4.

Comment: Is the pointer solution a valid solution? Looks like just obsfucating the fact that an internal routine is passed. Also, which ifort version are you using?

Comment: I agree, it is a bit strange if it is valid. Based on the way I interpret the Fortran 2003 standard it is valid because it says non-pointer procedure arguments has to be either module-, external-, intrinsic- or dummy procedure.

Comment: I use ifort 2021.10.0 which is right now the newest.

Comment: ifort 2021 in itself supports (most of) F2018, but it's unclear which OpenMP revision ifort 2021.10 supports. Note that ifx now replaces ifort.

Comment: Why is it unclear which OpenMP revision ifort 2021 supports? It says on Intel's web page to which I posted link in the answer.

Comment: Because there is some contradictory information on the [Intel site](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/release-notes/fortran-compiler-release-notes.html): *"Intel Fortran Compiler Classic (ifort) version 2021.10.0 [...] has been updated to include recent versions of 3rd party components, which include functional and security updates."*: Is OpenMP part of the 3rd party components? If yes, is the revision level part of the functional updates? You're probably right, though...

Comment: @PierU I doubt so, the third party packages will be actual software like gdb.